# UIWebView - css styling for html input button onmousedown

Tags: javascript, objective-c, css, uiwebview

I've got a local html resource loading in a UIWebView. I've been styling that html document to look like a UITableView with some UIButton(s). I've had pretty good success so far. I'm just trying to get a input type=button to work like a UIButton in the way that it turns it blue when you press on it. Unfortunately I don't know how to turn off or restyle the button turning greyish (which is the default way it works on a UIWebView) when you press on it. Heres my button:

```
<input class="iPhoneStandardButton"
        onmousedown="changeStyle(this,'iPhoneStandardButton_press');" 
        onmouseup="changeStyle(this,'iPhoneStandardButton');" 
        type="button"
        value="My Button" />
```

My changeStyle function (I've proven this works):

```
function changeStyle(element, newClassName){
   element.setAttribute("class", newClassName);
}
```

And my css:

```
.iPhoneStandardButton {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-size: 13;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.iPhoneStandardButton_press{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border: solid 1px #666666;
    background: #058CF5;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#058CF5), to(#015DE6));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #058CF5,  #015DE6);
    border-radius: 12px;
    font-size: 13;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

I'm happy with the styles, it just doesn't apply on onmousedown. It still shows as the default greyed blur button press which UIWebView/safari seems to enforce on all buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ontouchstart`.  The iOS Safari documentation lists `onmousedown`, but it did not work for me, either, and using `ontouchstart` fixed the problem.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW7 for a list of all the Javascript events Apple claims to support.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="iPhoneStandardButton"
        onclick="toggleStyle(this, 'iPhoneStandardButton', 'iPhoneStandardButton_press');" 
        type="button"
        value="My Button" />
```

---

```
function toggleStyle(element, defaultStyle, altStyle) {
    if (element.className == defaultStyle)
        element.className = altStyle;
    else
        element.className = defaultStyle;
}
```

Comment: This is onclick - I need onMousedown. I just figured out that there is no such thing as onmousedown on an iphone. Thanks for your answer though.